# Show that ${Ax_1,...,Ax_r}$ is a basis for $R(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $r$ and let $\{ x_1,...,x_r \}$ be a basis for $R(A^T)$. Show that $\{ Ax_1,...,Ax_r \}$ is a basis for $R(A)$.

I remember we did an example in class similar to this.

Maybe I can take the $A$ out and turn the set into $A(x_1,...x_r)$? Not sure where to go from there but I remember my teacher doing this.

Update: I found an example in the notes, and it said to prove that they are linearly independent. Not sure why I don't have to show that they span, though.

Comment: Are you sure of your editing?

Comment: If you're referring to the format, I accidentally overwrote the edit someone else made with an update, but I think I fixed it.

Comment: Oh, alright; that someone was me, in fact. :)

Comment: Oh, haha, sorry!

Comment: Since $\dim R(A)=\operatorname{rank} A=r$, it suffices to show that $\{Ax_1,\dots Ax_r\}\subseteq R(A)$ is linearly independent—any linearly independent set of $r$ vectors in $R(A)$ must span it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the $A$ out is the right idea. Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^rc_iAx_i=A\left(\sum_{i=1}^rc_ix_i\right)=A\mathbf v=0$. Then $\mathbf v\in\ker A$. But $\mathbf v\in\operatorname{im}A^T$ and $\operatorname{im}A^T=\ker A^\perp$, so $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf v=\sum_{i=1}^rc_i^2=0$, therefore $c_1=\dots=c_r=0$. The $Ax_i$ are thus linearly independent and since $\dim\operatorname{im}A=r$, they form a basis for $\operatorname{im}A$.

Comment: Does "im" mean image? If so my teacher has not gone over this, but I've heard that it's the same thing as the column space.

Comment: It is. If you think of the matrix $A$ as representing a linear transformation $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^m$, then the image of this transformation is the same as $A$’s column space.